# Induced Voltage calculation in rotating conductor

Tags: voltage, electromagnetism, electromagnetic

[image]

[image]

I have uploaded the example problem and the solution of it.

A positive charge will face force Q(vXB) in -z direction which will lead to separation of charges.

The separated charges create an electric field which will generate Q(E) force opposing the lorentz force. So, shouldn't the E be in z direction rather than -z ??

The lorentz force and Q(E) will balance each other and generate a potential difference with +ve down and -ve up and a magnitude of vBh.

Am I missing something ?? Please help me with this concept.

Comment: maybe you confused yourself with your first sketch where the direction of the Lorentz-force goes upwards instead of downwards as in the example with the rotating cylinder.  
Your considerations concerning the force coming from the electric field counterbalances the Lorentz-force appear to be correct

Comment: In 2nd case, direction of E will be down to up. So, it should be z ?? But solution says -z

Comment: ...but you measure the voltage from up to down which appears to me as -z direction..., ...thus "negative" voltage.

Comment: I am not able to understand. Please elaborate.

Comment: if the Lorentz-force forces positive charge carriers down to the bottom the resulting electric field is from bottom to top (from plus to minus). Your voltmeter usually has a plus-tip and a minus-tip (in this case: sliders) The plus-slider connects to the top of the cylinder and the minus-slider to the bottom. Because the electric field is directed from bottom to top a positive voltage could only be measured from bottom to top. If  the direction of measuerement is the other way around the polarity has to be in opposite direction.